# Realm support for ARM64 in v0.79+ causes other native libraries to not be found on a Galaxy S6

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, realm

Using Realm 0.79 or above causes our built apk structure to look like this:

```
...
    /lib
      /arm64-v8a
        librealm-jni.so
      /armeabi
        libaviary_moalite.so
        libaviary_native.so
        libcpuinfo.so
        librealm-jni.so
...
```

Third party library code is no longer able to find and load libraries like libcpuinfo.so or libaviary_moalite.so because 64 bit Android is only looking in the arm64-v8a directory that solely exists due to the 64 bit realm native library file. Realm 0.78 and below don't cause the arm64-v8a directory to be present in the apk file and third party libraries are able to find the native libraries they need. Lollipop seems to stop searching for native library files in other compatible architecture directories once it finds the architecture directory most suited for the device.

What's the best way to fix this?
I can either remove that directory entirely before packaging the apk (which seems to work for the time being)
Or, is there a better way?

Comment: That's too bad? Did you have a question?

Comment: Here is how you can override that setting. https://source.android.com/source/64-bit-builds.html Thought, this doesn't mean that it will work. It most likely won't work unless you can find those missing libraries for 64bit as well, or those same libraries that have been written for both 32bit and 64bit. Have you searched for those?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk that's the problem. Those other libraries aren't necessarily missing. In the example above, the non 64 bit libraries for Aviary work fine in a 64 bit device so (understandably) there is no incentive for them to create a 64 bit native library. And we have multiple third party native libraries, so we can't assume they're all going to create 64 bit versions. The real question is how to take advantage of some third party libraries like Realm that optimize to the best architecture while still being able to use the libraries that don't.

Comment: Right now removing the 64 bit binaries are unfortunately the best approach. Realm just had a similar problem with Fresco from Facebook: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1092

Comment: I'm currently stuck with the same issue, did find a solution? Did you remove the arm64 stuff and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your app level build gradle:

```
android {
....
defaultConfig {
    ....
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }
}
```

}

it will remove 64-bit version of realm library.

2.Copy all of your native libraries from "armeabi" and paste it to "areabi-v7a" folder.